# Would a two-particle pure momentum eigenstate scatter in QED?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, eigenvalue

Okay, I know a momentum eigenstate is not realizable in practice since it's not normalizable.  But say we ignore the normalizability constraint, and just apply the rest of the theory.  My question is, if we start with a two-electron system in momentum eigenstate $<\vec p_1, \vec p_2>$ with no external field, then according to QED, would it exhibit some kind of scattering over time?

My initial thoughts:

1. In the one-particle Schrodinger theory, a superposition of two momenta with no external potential would be time-independent, by linearity and the time-independence of each momentum state separately.  But that's just a single-particle superposition, not a multi-particle state.
2. Maybe the multi-particle Schrodinger equation could give insight as well, but I would imagine QFT would provide a deeper answer.
3. Classically, the amount of scattering would depend very much on the positions of the particles, not just their momenta.

Really, #3 is the crux of the question: how could it even make sense to talk about scattering without some degree of localization?  But how could there be a correspondence to classical physics if there's no scattering (or perhaps there doesn't have to be since this phenomenon is inherently microscopic)?  Yet I think I've read that, in particle accelerators, the particles are practically (though of course not quite) in momentum eigenstates.  But maybe in that case they are only being scattered by the external field?  So you can see my confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Momentum eigenstates are plane waves of infinite extent. This means that they must overlap spatially everywhere, thereby having some kind of scattering that is possibly seen as a weighted average of the possible scatterings. (That's the answer to your #3)

The problem is that we do NOT know how to figure out the energy eigenstates of the multiparticle QFT system, and can only try to use asymptotic input and output states in the approximation that these plane waves do not interact. Those asymptotic states are mapped by the adiabatic tuning on or off of the interaction term into the energy eigenstates of the fully interacting Hamiltonian, which is why QFT works the way it does, even though it seems like we wrote down something that should only obey the free Hamiltonian at the asymptotic limits.

That is, the true Hamiltonian eigenstate of interacting QFT does not have $\left < p_1 , p_2 \mid p_1^\prime , p_2^\prime \right >$ orthogonally proportional to Dirac delta distributions (assuming we may label the states as momentum product eigenstates at all). There is sufficient overlap with other such states that you observe scattering. Because the asymptotic input and output states actually solve the full interacting Hamiltonian despite appearances not to, their overlap integrated transition amplitudes also show this behaviour.

Comment: That bit about "asymptotic states are mapped...fully interacting Hamiltonian" -- do you have a good starter reference (preferably online) that fleshes that out without getting too bogged down in the details, so I can hopefully start to ease my way into it?

Comment: The book I was using was Anthony Duncan's Conceptual Framework of QFT. There is pretty much nothing like it elsewhere. Vastly worth the cost price.

Comment: Looks great, thanks, I will check it out!